# How do I connect the app running using Nodejs with the service dependencies running using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis

I am trying to run this repository (https://github.com/energywebfoundation/ssi-hub). I am running the app separately with service dependencies being run in docker-compose. However, my app is not able to connect to the redis service running in the docker-compose file. I get the following error

```
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)
Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
    at RedisClient.on_error (/home/danish/Desktop/ssi-hub/node_modules/redis/index.js:342:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/danish/Desktop/ssi-hub/node_modules/redis/index.js:223:14)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'redis'
}
```

I am using this configuration file to run redis service in docker composer

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_USERNAME: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: dev-test
    networks:
      - main
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  nats:
    container_name: nats
    image: synadia/nats-server:nightly
    volumes:
      - ./config/:/etc/nats
    command: '-c /etc/nats/nats.conf'
    networks:
      - main
    ports:
      - '4222:4222'
      - '8222:8222'
      - '9222:9222'
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:${REDIS_VERSION}
    command: redis-server --requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - $PWD/redis-data:/var/lib/redis
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    environment:
      - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=master
    networks:
      - main
networks:
  main:
```

I tried my best to find an answer online but I am not able to solve this problem. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you post the connection strings you are using? And how you are running redis? Typically if you are running this using docker-compose you can use a docker network and add an network alias for each service, then you can use this as connection strings, this way each service will connect to each other on their private network.  See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#networks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try cloning this repo:

https://github.com/wildone/nats-test

Then run `docker compose up`.

Can't see any errors and UI comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer. I had some problems with the configuration in the .env file in this repository (https://github.com/energywebfoundation/ssi-hub). I changed the host name to localhost and i was able to connect docker services with node application. Thanks